# MatchError for PartialFunctions composition with orElse

Tags: scala, partialfunction

While writing a Specs2 specification for an Actor I got a somewhat puzzling `MatchError` for composition of several partial functions.

A minimal example:

```
val testPf1 = PartialFunction[Any, Boolean]{ case 2 ⇒ true }
val testPf2 = PartialFunction[Any, Boolean]{ case 1 ⇒ true }
val testPf = testPf1 orElse testPf2
testPf.isDefinedAt(1)
testPf.isDefinedAt(2)
testPf(1)
testPf(2)
```

leads to the output:

```
testPf1: PartialFunction[Any,Boolean] = <function1>
testPf2: PartialFunction[Any,Boolean] = <function1>
testPf: PartialFunction[Any,Boolean] = <function1>
res0: Boolean = true
res1: Boolean = true
scala.MatchError: 1 (of class java.lang.Integer)
    at com.dasgip.controller.common.informationmodel.programming.parametersequence.A$A161$A$A161$$anonfun$testPf1$1.apply(PFTest.sc0.tmp:33)
    at com.dasgip.controller.common.informationmodel.programming.parametersequence.A$A161$A$A161$$anonfun$testPf1$1.apply(PFTest.sc0.tmp:33)
    at scala.PartialFunction$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PFTest.sc0.tmp:243)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PFTest.sc0.tmp:163)
    at #worksheet#.#worksheet#(PFTest.sc0.tmp:36)
```

That totally confused me. If for a given input `isDefinedAt` on the composition of two partial functions returns `true`, I would expect that I can also `apply` it  to the same input.

Comment: I was alerted by the puzzler guy http://scalapuzzlers.com/#pzzlr-052

Comment: Well, with a heavy heart, I flagged it as duplicate myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hence, I learned that changing the first two lines to:

```
val testPf1: PartialFunction[Any, Boolean] = { case 2 ⇒ true }
val testPf2: PartialFunction[Any, Boolean] = { case 1 ⇒ true }
```

makes the composition work as expected.

The reason for the `MatchError` was that with

```
PartialFunction[Any, Boolean]{ case 2 => true }
```

I actually seem to be calling `PartialFunction.apply`, which converts a `Function1` to a `PartialFunction`.

So that the statement expands to

```
 PartialFunction.apply[Any, Boolean](_ match { case 2 => true })
```

and then converted to

```
{ case x => f(x) }
```

which, of course, will always return `true` for `isDefined` and throw a MatchError on input not matched by `f`.

Comment: That's a good one. I've only used the corrected form; always asking what is the expected type of the case block or "pattern matching anon fun" since that determines whether you get a PF. I think the apply method here is misnamed; it was introduced in the very good PF revamp; but this is a bad gotcha. Boy, naming is really hard.